# Why is my fetched data not appearing in my React hooks component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to load data into my component for it to be displayed. I thought the issue was that I wasn't using async/await for the fetch, but even after adding that it still is not loading. I am logging out the "offerings" and it is just showing the empty array. How do I keep the component from rendering until after the data is loaded??

Thanks in advance!

```
  const [offerings, setOfferings] = useState([]);

  const loadData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://52.207.83.69` + `${CRUD_OFFERING}`);
    setOfferings(await res.json()); 
    console.log(offerings, 'offerings')
  };

  useEffect(async () => {
    navbarToggle();
    await loadData();
  }, []);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const modalState = useSelector((state) => state.modal);
  const modalToggle = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: MODAL_TOGGLE,
      payload: !modalState.show,
    });
    ga.event("navbar_requestdemo_clicked");
  };
  const navbarOpenState = useSelector((state) => state.navbar);
  const navbarToggle = () => {
    if (!navbarOpenState.open) return;
    dispatch({
      type: NAVBAR_OPEN,
      payload: false,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center bg-color-white fc-px-15"
      onClick={navbarToggle}
    >
      <div className={homeStyles["padded-body"] + " col-11 p-0"}>
        <div className=" position-relative bg-color-white">
          <div className={homeStyles["img-holder"]}></div>
          <div className="col-12 column position-absolute top-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-lg-6 col-12 fc-mt-2">
              <SearchBar />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="position-absolute top-50 translateY-middle">
            <div className="position-relative">
              <h1 className={`${homeStyles["hero-text"]} font-weight-bolder`}>
                Building
                <br />
                Meaningful
                <br />
                Engagement
              </h1>
              <button
                className="btn btn-primary-round mt-3 px-3 py-2"
                onClick={() => {
                  modalToggle();
                }}
              >
                Request access
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          id={homeStyles["discover-section"]}
          className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
        >
          <div className="col-12 column">
            <h4 className="font-weight-bold">Discover</h4>
            <div
              id={homeStyles["offer-section"]}
              className="row justify-content-center align-items-center"
            >
              {!offerings?.length && 
                <h4 className="text-center">There are no active offerings.</h4>
              }
            </div>
            <OfferingCarousal
              offeringsList={offerings}
              name={"Offerings"}
            />
            <div id={homeStyles["consultancy-section"]} className="">
              <div className="row">
                <div
                  className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center col-lg-6 col-12 px-0 mt-3 mb-4"
                  id={homeStyles["consultancy-div"]}
                >
                  <div className="col-12 column p-5">
                    <h1 className="font-weight-bold">Add your consultancy</h1>
                    <h5 className="mt-4">
                      Reach more people and organizations
                    </h5>
                    <Link href="/consultancies">
                      <button className="btn btn-primary-round mt-4">
                        Learn more
                      </button>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-lg-6 col-12 px-0">
                  <img
                    src="/images/Rachael_glasses_home_page.jpg"
                    id={homeStyles["consultant-img"]}
                    className="mt-3"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomeNew;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the data is present before you consume the data.

```js
  const [offerings, setOfferings] = useState([]);

  const loadData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://52.207.83.69` + `${CRUD_OFFERING}`);
    setOfferings(res.json()); 
    console.log(res, 'offerings')
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    navbarToggle();
    loadData(); // await has no affect inside useEffect for top level functions
  }, []);

  // removed internal code for clarity 
  const dispatch = useDispatch(...yourCode);
  const modalState = useSelector(...yourCode);
  const modalToggle = () => {...yourCode};
  const navbarOpenState = useSelector(...yourCode);
  const navbarToggle = () => {...yourCode};

  // check after the hooks and before the consuming the data
  if(!offerings && !offerings.length) return <>No offerings</>;

  return <div>your side nav</div>;
};
```

It's also good practice to catch asynchronous errors as they occur to prevent your a single component form breaking your whole app. You can also take advantage of the [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) and put in loading and error states too.

```js
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [offerings, setOfferings] = useState([]);

  const loadData = async () => {
    try {
     setError(false);
     setLoading(true);
     const res = await fetch(`http://52.207.83.69` + `${CRUD_OFFERING}`);
     setOfferings(res.json()); 
   } catch (e){
     setError(true)
   } finally {
     setLoading(false);
   }
  };

  // other code from above


  if(error) return <>error</>;
  if(loading) return <>loading</>;
  if(!offerings && !offerings.length) return <>No offerings</>;
  return <div>your side nav</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

async function can't be put in the useEffect hook directly.
https://prnt.sc/1lu7vdc
It can be like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    ...
    (async ()=>{

        await loadData()

    })();
}, []);
```

But in your case, I think you don't need to wait until loadData function is executed.
Just make sure you handle exceptions on the rendering for Empty data.